# Given the link below how to slide with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have little knowledge about js or jquery, i need your help :
[Slide Example](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/samples)

like that.  Given the link below how to slide with jQuery.

Comment: Have you read the source for the Slide Example you link to?  What about it do you not understand?  Or, if it is a shorter list, what abou it do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the [Cycle plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/), but still you'll need to code by yourself.